# Jmeter Secure WS- Security SOAP Webservices for encrypted data

Tags: jmeter, soapui

I'm planning to do the performance test using JMeter for WS-Security SOAP Webservices. I observed that the data that is sent in the request is being encrypted using Apache CXF. Is there any where for me to have these values sent to the server and get the value using Jmeter. I've looked into
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/take-pain-out-load-testing-secure-web-services

as well but I couldn't get pass through due to "A security error was encountered when verifying the message."

After I tried the solution provided by Dmitri, I could see the following differences in the request by  SOAP UI and JMeter. The following are missing in Jmeter request while present in SOAP UI

```
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-5082">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ser" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>qSF7n7bkl2cKYVZvDwT7ur77AdSeT4/kqbdEqPfkzVA=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
```

and

```
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-5081">
            <wsu:Created>2017-10-24T18:39:53.349Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2017-10-24T18:41:33.349Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
```

For the timestamp, I have manually added the wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp to the request like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://www.wso2.org/types">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
           <wsu:Timestamp>
               <wsu:Created>#CREATED#</wsu:Created>
               <wsu:Expires>#EXPIRES#</wsu:Expires>
           </wsu:Timestamp>
       </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <typ:greet>           
           <name>Blazemeter</name>
       </typ:greet>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I still face the same issue. 
Jmeter system.properties file is updated to include the keystore information.
Under HTTP Request Sampler, I see 
Response code: 500
Response message:

No error is seen on Jmeter logs as well.

[image]

Any help over this is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache CXF is a [service framework](http://cxf.apache.org/), not the encryption method so in order to get an answer you need to provide as much information as possible.

You can also consider using [jmeter-wssecurity](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity) sampler for load testing your web-service endpoint, it provides simple GUI allowing choosing signature algorithm, digest algorithm, certificates, etc. so if you are uncertain regarding your web service security configuration you can play with it.

You can install the plugin as `WS Security for SOAP` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager WS Security]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, this actually helps to an extent. I've tried this implementation in Jmeter 3.0 version and still receiving a security error. I've added additional details to the question. Kindly check it.

Comment: I can only suggest adding [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it to send at least [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `text/xml` or `application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8` or whatever your application expects. You might need to send [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) header as well. With regards to encryption - you will need to figure out the correct configuration yourself, there are too many options.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, your suggestion helped me a lot. I could able to check on the server logs and have included the timestamp. This now works. Thanks again.